# Memory is not full released after deleting all QPushButtons in QTApp

Tags: qt, memory, window, ram, qpushbutton

I am creating a program containing `QPushButtons`. The problem is when i add `QPushButtons` memory(RAM) is increasing but when i delete all added buttons memory is not fully releasing.

```
void TempTest ::addSLOT()
{
  li= new QList<QPushButton*>;
  for(int i=0;i<50000;i++)
   {
     QPushButton *p = new QPushButton;
     p->setText("sample");
     p->setFixedSize(100,100);
     li->append(p);
   }
}
void TempTest ::removeSLOT()
{
  while(li->count())
   {
     QPushButton*p= li->at(0);
     li->removeAt(0);
     delete p;
   }
   delete li;
}
```

1. Initialy memory is 2.0 mb
2. After adding memory increased to 49.3 mb
3. After deleting memory decreased to 4.1 mb

Is there 2.1 mb of RAM never ba released?

i am checking Ram in Windows Task manager, there is Memory column there.
i was having Ram issue in some other project thatswhy i write this sample code to check if All memory releasing or not.

Moreover if i repeat that process--
again add and delete Buttons - 4.4 mb
again add and delete Buttons - 4.9 mb
again add and delete Buttons - 4.6 mb
again add and delete Buttons - 4.4 mb
again add and delete Buttons - 5.4 mb
again add and delete Buttons - 4.9 mb
again add and delete Buttons - 4.6 mb

we can clearly see variations in memory but it never goes back to 2.0 mb

Comment: And if you repeat this multiple times, does the memory keep increasing?

Comment: How you see memory usage? With which tool?

Comment: i have added information.